# How to design the circuit to connect a status input and ground from the external device, to one of the GPIO pins on the ESP32

Tags: circuit-design, opto-isolator

I'm a professional software developer, but a novice electronics designer.

My current project is to write some software to interface to an external device. The project includes building a small circuit board to host an ESP32 microcontroller (which I have done before).

The external device needs to be electrically isolated from my PCB, so I'm looking at using an optocoupler. Specifically, I have bought some of these 'Isocom, ISQ74X DC Input Phototransistor Output Quad Optocoupler, Through Hole, 16-Pin PDIP'

How should I design the circuit to connect a status input and ground from the external device, to one of the GPIO pins on the ESP32?

I'd also like a status LED on my PCB to indicate if the external input is 24 V DC (LED on) or 0 V DC (LED off). This will be a debug tool for the customer.

Below I have put together a rough circuit design, which I'm sure is wrong :-) Could you advise what I need to do to make this work, including resistor values you would recommend?

[image: My circuit attempt]

Comment: The input pin on the microcontroller will have an input impedance of megaohms or higher. No current will flow through D3.

Comment: "Optocoupler basics". That's not your question. " how to design the circuit to connect a status input and ground from the external device, to one of the GPIO pins on the ESP32.". That's your question. Please ask your actual question in the title.

Comment: @Transistor so should the LED D3 be moved to connect to Gnd in parallel to R2? I assume with another resistor inline. How do I calculate the resistor values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment you won't get any significant current going into the microcontroller's CMOS input so D3 won't light. As you have realised, the correct approach will be to connect it in parallel with R2.

We need to watch a couple of things here:

1. Opto-isolators have a "current transfer ratio" which determines the maximum current the output transistor will provide for a given input LED current. (You've shown a photo-diode on your schematic but the device is actually a photo-transistor.)
2. We're working off 3.3 V so we haven't a lot of headroom to light an LED given that there will be some voltage drop across the opto-isolator output.

Let's have a look at the [datasheet](http://isocom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/ISQ1_Q5_Q74.pdf):

- For the ISQ74X we see that the CTR can be as low as 12.5% when I<sub>F</sub>, the LED forward current, is 16 mA and there is 5 V available for the output transistor.
- Your 4.7 kΩ input resistor will limit the LED current to about 5 mA so the worst-case max we could get on the output would be about 5 × 12.5% = 0.6 mA which wouldn't be great for an LED. Go for 20 mA on the LED so we need about 1 kΩ. But now we need to check the power dissipated in the 1 kΩ resistor: $ P = V<sup>2</sup> / R = 22<sup>2</sup> / 1000 = 0.484 W so you'd need at least 0.5 W capability. (The 22 V assumes a 2 V drop across the LED. The 0.5 W could be split across two 500 Ω series resistors, etc.)
- Now we should be able to get about 20 mA × 12.5% = 2.5 mA minimum on the other side.

[image]

*Figure 1. LED I-V curves. Image mine - [LEDnique.com](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/).*

The graph shows us that voltage drop on the LED depends on the colour (because of the dopants used to generate the various wavelengths of light). I'd recommend an LED in the red - green range because of their lower V<sub>F</sub>. Any of the high-brightness types should give plenty of light for an indicator at 2 mA or so.

- Let's assume that the LED drops about 2 V at 2 mA and the output transistor drops about 0.5 V. (The datasheet doesn't specify the latter.) That leaves 3.3 - 2.5 = 0.8 V for the series resistor. R = V / I = 0.8 / 0.002 = 400 Ω. Start experimenting with something in the 270 - 470 Ω range, take some measurements and adjust to suit.
- R2 can be 100 kΩ or so just to make sure that the input is pulled down but without consuming excessive current when the input is high.

It's tricky enough, isn't it!

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, it is tricky enough. I'll test this out on Monday

Comment: Worked great! Appreciate your help with that.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJzQWz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This should do the job for you.

[image: Input and GPIO Voltages]

[image: Input and LED current]

Comment: I assume, R2 is not a real component but simulates the current transfer ratio of the coupler, nice idea. The GPIO will need an activated pullup resistor to provide a proper "high" level.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately CircuitLab does not have a model for an optoisolator, so I made this. I made no attempt to match the properties of a real component. There may be enough leakage through the LED to function as a pull-up. Otherwise, the ESP32 might have weak pull-up that can be programmed..